# Cannot import correct version of numpy on OS X Mavericks

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, osx-mavericks

I have upgraded from Mountain Lion to Mavericks ande also updated Macports and its outdated packages. I have installed numpy 1.7, but the problem is the one used by python is still numpy 1.6. The following are some information about my system.

`>> python -c 'import numpy; print numpy.__version__'` gives

```
1.6.2
```

which shows the active numpy version is 1.6.2

`>> port installed | grep numpy` gives

```
py27-numpy @1.7.1_0 (active)
```

which shows the active numpy version is 1.7.1_0

`>> port installed | grep python` gives

```
gnome-doc-utils @0.20.10_0+python27 (active)
gtk-doc @1.18_0+python27 (active)
ipython_select @0.3_1 (active)
opencv @2.4.6.1_2+python27 (active)
py27-ipython @0.13.2_0+notebook+parallel+scientific
py27-ipython @1.1.0_0+scientific
py27-ipython @1.1.0_0+notebook+parallel+scientific (active)
py27-wxpython-3.0 @2.9.5.0_0 (active)
py27-wxpython-devel @2.9.4.0_0
python24 @2.4.6_10 (active)
python27 @2.7.5_0
python27 @2.7.5_1 (active)
python_select @0.3_2
python_select @0.3_3 (active)
swig-python @2.0.9_0
swig-python @2.0.10_0 (active)
xorg-libxcb @1.9.1_0+python27 (active)
xorg-xcb-proto @1.8_0+python27 (active)
```

which shows, the active python version is python27.

Also, `port select python` gives

```
Available versions for python:
    none
    python24
    python25-apple
    python26-apple
    python27
    python27-apple (active)
```

Comment: And what is `numpy.__file__`? You're probably picking up the system one. Does `which python` tells you it's in `/opt/local`?

Comment: On the command line, run `which python` or `ls -l $(which python)` to check for links.  Also, please type `port select python`, to see which python port is telling the system to use.

Comment: @void: what is wrong with macports? I am using it because it is suggested as similar tool as apt in Ubuntu. Actually, I start to use Mac only a few months ago.

Comment: @skyuuka Nothing, but a lot of users prefer [homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

Comment: @Evert:`numpy.__file__=/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/__init__.pyc` and `which python` gives `/opt/local/bin/python`

Comment: Hmm, what is `import sys; print sys.path`?  You should expect it to be looking for packages and modules primarily (if not only) in  `/opt/local/Library/`, not `/System/Library/`

Comment: @askewchan: thanks for the recommendation, I will consider it.

Comment: @skyuuka That wasn't necessarily a recommendation :P  I use macports myself.  But some feel strongly: the title of  the homebrew page is [Homebrew — MacPorts driving you to drink? Try Homebrew!](http://brew.sh/)

Comment: You must have a `PYTHONPATH` that points to the System numpy library. By itself, the macports Python should pick up the macports numpy, but a `PYTHONPATH` variable takes precedence to the default places to look for modules. Try cleaning up your `PYTHONPATH` therefore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the apple-installed version of python, you can see this by the fact that

```
port select python
```

gives you

```
python27-apple (active)
```

Remedy this with:

```
sudo port select python python27
```

---

If this:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

still shows that python is looking in `/System/Library` instead of (or before) `/opt/local/Library` for packages, then the apple versions of packages might be imported.  To solve this, you might be able to fix it by using a `.pth` file with  [`site`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html) to modify your [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path).

Comment: Thanks, but it does not solve the problem. I tried to switch the python version, it never works.

Comment: Can you switch to `python27` (not `-apple`) and then run python, and `import sys; print sys.path` and see if it's looking in `/opt/local/Library` or `/System/Library`? IT could be related to https://trac.macports.org/ticket/34763

Comment: Sure, I am using the one without `-apple`, but `sys.path` is looking into both `opt/local/Library` and `/System/Library`.

Comment: So that's the problem, the old numpy is in `/System/Library` and due to that bug, that path must come first before the `/opt/local/Library`. You might be able to fix it by using [`site`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html) to modify your [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path).